# Providing status of large file processing in ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a Razor/MVC application that involves uploading a large XML file for data processing. While this file is processing, I would like to give the user the current status of the processing, such as "we have processed X out of Y items".

The processing is done entirely by the .NET framework so is there a way, once I pass the file from the javascript uploader to the c# processor, to update the status message after a new section has finished processing? If so, what would be the correct way to get this information?

Thank you

Comment: signalR ? long polling ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into these options and see if i can make them work for my scenario